# [Java]: How to fetch the nearest smaller number from a sorted list when a number requested is not in the list

Tags: java, arrays, list, data-structures

I want to fetch the nearest smaller number from a sorted list when a number requested is not in the list. Eg: List {10,14,55,97} and the requested number is 
12, then I want to return 10. But the code below returns 14. This code searches on both the directions in the list. I want to search only on the lower side of the list.

I tried the following code:

```
 public static int getClosestInteger(final List<Integer> listOfIntegers, final int requestedNumber) {

    int low = 0;
    int high = listOfIntegers.size() - 1;

    if (high < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The list cannot be empty");
    }

    while (low < high) {
        final int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        assert (mid < high);

        final int digit1 = Math.abs(listOfIntegers.get(mid) - requestedNumber);
        final int digit2 = Math.abs(listOfIntegers.get(mid + 1) - requestedNumber);
        if (digit2 <= digit1) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            high = mid;
        }
    }
    return listOfIntegers.get(high);
}
```

Any suggestions on what to change?

Comment: Use `TreeSet` instead of the list.  It has a bunch of methods for getting things like the "next value below" or "next value above" a certain value.

Comment: Thanks. It helped. This worked:

final TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(listOfIntegers);
 set.floor(requestedNumber);

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is a variant on the binary search algorithm.
Check out the [Procedure for finding the leftmost element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure_for_finding_the_leftmost_element)

In pseudo code:

```
function binary_search_leftmost(A, n):
    L := 0
    R := n
    while L < R:
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] < T:
            L := m + 1
        else:
            R := m
    return L
```

This will find the number of elements less than T. And since arrays start at 0, all you need to do in the end is

```
if A[L] == T:
    return A[L]
else:
    return A[L-1]
```

It's slightly different from your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Or...

you could add that number to the list, find its index, decrement by one and then remove it from the list :D

Comment: Yeah, if you knew where to add the new element, you could go straight to the element that you're looking for.  You wouldn't need to mess around adding the element then removing it.  I don't think this answer makes the process any easier.